# Declaring function inside class component vs inside functional component

Tags: javascript, function, class, components, constants

I am playing with function syntax inside and outside class components. Can anyone explain to me why the print function works when written like this

```
const UploadButton = (props)=> {

    const fileName = 'myfile';


    props.getFileName(fileName)

    function print(){console.log('onClick worked')}

    return(

        <div>
            <input onClick= {print()} type="file" id = {fileName}/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

but when i write it like i would when declaring it inside a class component:

`print(){console.log('onClick worked')}`

i get this error

```
 Line 10:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ";"

   8 |  props.getFileName(fileName)
   9 | 
> 10 |   print(){console.log('onClick worked')}
     |          ^
```

Comment: What's the error? Also try whitespacing it to make it more readable.

Comment: @JackBashford i've added it to the answer

Comment: You're trying to call it - show the enclosing class please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is not tied with React but fundamentally is a `method` vs. `function` thing in JavaScript.
When you declare functions with some context it becomes a `method`. So, In a class setup, the functions are actually methods.
In Javascript, it is possible to declare a function within another function, that is why this works

```
const UploadButton = (props)=> {
    const fileName = 'myfile';
    props.getFileName(fileName)
    function print(){console.log('onClick worked')}
    return(
        <div>
            <input onClick= {print()} type="file" id = {fileName}/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

But when you don't specify the `function` keyword and the declaration is not inside of class it throws error.

```
print(){console.log('onClick worked')}
Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ";"
```

If you rather used an arrow function here `print=()=>{console.log('onClick worked')}`, it would work because its a function expression and is treated as a normal variable declaration scoped to the enclosing function.

Comment: so are you saying that inside a `const` functions aren't methods, and so the `function` keyword is needed, but inside class components they are, and so the `function` keyword is not needed?

Comment: Yes. const declarations are normal function expressions but inside of a class component they are methods of the class, so the function keyword is not needed.
And the same applies to other variables in a class setup, they are called class members and don't need keywords for declaration.

Answer (score 0):

```
print(){console.log('onClick worked')}
```

I think when you write this in a functional component the compiler does not know that you are trying to define a function and it is rather trying to execute the print function, hence it is expecting a ';'

However, In class based components when you define a function using the above syntax, when the class is converted to a function, the print method will be added to its prototype.

Answer (score 0):

One issue that you're having with your functional component is that you're calling the `print` function, then passing whatever it returns, which is `undefined` in this case, to the `onClick` handler of your `input` element.

Your `JSX` for the `input` element should look like this:

```js
const UploadButton = (props)=> {
  // ...
  return (
    <div>
      <input onClick={print} type="file" id={fileName}/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

When dealing with `class components`, however, your `UploadButton` component, should look like the following:

```js
class UploadButton extends React.Component {
  print() {
    console.log('onClick worked')
  }

  render() {
    // ...
    this.props.getFileName(fileName)

    return (
      <div>
        <input onClick={this.print} type="file" id = {fileName}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

---

Also, you probably shouldn't be using an `input` element as your `UploadButton`. Just use a `button` element instead, something like the following example:

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <label for="file">Choose file to upload</label>
    <input type="file" id={fileName} />
  </div>

  <div>
    <!--Should be something along the lines of `this.handleSubmit` 
        rather than `this.print`, but you get the idea-->
    <button onClick={this.print}>Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```